# Nodes are not visible (blank window)

Tags: java, javafx

My code:

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Base.java

```
@DefaultProperty("children")
public class Base extends HBox {

    public final ObservableList<Node> children;
    public final VBox foundation;

    public Base() {
        foundation = new VBox();
        children = foundation.getChildren();
        super.getChildren().add(foundation);
    }

    public final ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import sample.Base?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<Base xmlns:fx="gui" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <Button text="test"/>
    </children>
</Base>
```

The Scene object in the Main class is not null. Controller.java is empty.
Why doesn't my button show up? Any ideas?

BTW. The stage (window) is being sized like there IS some button, but it is not visible (maybe it's under some node? but how come?)

I'm using OpenJDK & OpenJFX (14.0.1)

Comment: because you just add an empty VBox to the HBox

Comment: @Joe do you know what properties are for? please read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html

Comment: Overriding `getChildren()` like this is a terrible idea as it's breaking the no surprises requirement: `Parent.getChildren` returns a list containing nodes with a parent identical to the node owning the property. In your case the children are those of a different node. This probably messes things up during layout...

Comment: @fabian Thank you for your response! You are probably right - I just changed "children" property to "elements" and the button is visible now. Thanks! PS. You should add an answer here

Comment: As well as the `getParent()` mismatch, you have `getChildren()` and `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` returning lists whose contents are not equal, which could also cause mayhem in layout. This is a great example of why it's preferable to use aggregation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @James_D That's true, but how can I create a custom node without extending at least Parent?

Comment: @ImNotARobot You can't... You could make `Base` just a subclass of `Object`, and define a `public Node getView()` method that returns the underlying `VBox`. That lets you choose how much API of the underlying node you expose (via the return type of the method, `Node`, `Parent`, `Region`, etc.). It does make it harder (though not impossible) to use with FXML, I admit.

Comment: @James_D Thank you. Are you able to provide me some small FXML example of your idea?

Comment: If `Base` is the root of the FXML, then you can just have the FXML exactly as it is, and then do `Base root = fxmlLoader.load();` `Scene scene = new Scene(root.getView());`. If it's not the root, then it's a bit more work, but I think doing `<fx:define><Base fx:id="base">...</Base></fx:define>` and then, e.g. `<BorderPane center="${base.view}">` would work. I haven't tested that, though, and it is pretty clunky.